# Can now use BreezeJS without having to use EF?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, kendo-ui, breeze

Previously you had to use Entity Framework  as Breeze connected directly to the DbContext and that object did not exist elsewhere.
There is the notion of creating Metadata by hand(ie by T4)
I have access to the SQL server where every Table has its own crud usp (SSMS Tools Pack) the ashx does all the RMI into the DB, generates the json schema etc and the DTO service model.  I have looked at WCF service layer (http://davybrion.github.io/Agatha/) but  monolith EF seems to be everywhere. I have tried Angular I am quite happy to use ADO or Dapper.NET is there connectivity for BreezeJS is to a high performance back-end (Micro-ORM) or should I use Kendo DataSource (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview). This is for a Hybrid Mobile App, that need frictionless data.  Anyone else found an easy ClientSide/Server Side JSON Data integration system that is not so bloated? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Breeze without EF.  This needs to be promoted better.

The [Breeze.ContextProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Breeze.Server.ContextProvider/) package does not depend on EF.  It has a `ContextProvider` class that handles turning the JSON from the client into server-side .NET entities.  You subclass `ContextProvider` to implement the part that does the actual saving to the database.

[breeze.server.net](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net) provides two implementations: Breeze.ContextProvider.EF for Entity Framework, and Breeze.ContextProvider.NH for NHibernate.  You can look at these for inspiration about how to build the Dapper implementation.

One of the tricky bits is performing the add and delete operations in the right order.  For instance, if I'm adding a Customer and some related Orders, the Customer needs to be added to the DB before the Orders.  EF sorts the adds automatically, but NH does not, so we have a `SortDependencies()` method in  [NHRelationshipFixer](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider.NH/NHRelationshipFixer.cs).  You may need to do something similar if your micro-ORM does not do it for you.

If you come up with an implementation for a micro-ORM, please consider contributing it to the community.